# Python ctype for using libc.so.6 Linux and libc.dylib Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, ctype

I've been reading about `ctype` and the usage of dynamic libs.

I'm now able to use libs in:

1. Windows using `windll.kernel32`
2. Linux using `libc.so.6`

Under Windows I'm able to open other programs using:

```
createProcessA(..long_param_list..)
```

Now I want to do the same for Linux and Mac OSX, but I don't know how to find the right function name.

On Windows I use `cdll.msvcrt` calling `createProcessA`.

Does anyone know where to find the function references for Linux and Mac?

Under OS X I've been using `/usr/lib/libc.dylib`, but I have no clue on where to find the information I need.

Comment: What do you want to do? What functionality do you need? You shouldn't have to use ctypes for simply spawning a process.

Comment: I'm currently playing around with debuggers. I want to write my own small debugger that can attach to a process or start it. At Windows this is working quite good but I'm kind of stuck at the other OS.

Comment: hi cb0, are you reading the book named <Gray Hat Python>?

Comment: Hi Jet, yes it was from this book. Sadly I never finished the OS X debugger :( and moved on to other things. But it was fun diving into this part of python.